# Django search genders

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

Lets say I have a model

**models.py**

```
class Profile
gender = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(_('gender'),
                                              choices=GENDER_CHOICES,
                                              blank=True,
                                              null=True)
```

**forms.py**

```
GENDER_CHOICES = (
        (1, _('Male')),
        (2, _('Female')),
    )

class searchForm:

 box = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
                                      choices = GENDER_CHOICES,
                                      widget  = forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
                                      label   = 'Search',
                                     )
```

I need search for users and display them male or female in my profiles page.

Comment: what do you mean by search for users and display them male or female? Are you displaying 2 separate lists, or you want to show the gender of the current logged in user?

Comment: I would write a method on the model that returns the gender of the Profile as a string, just get Profile.gender and retrieve the string from the constant tuple GENDER_CHOICES. I mean, some method like: get_gender_as_str(), then you can render it on the template. profile.get_gender_as_str

Answer (score 2):

Django provides a special function for each field with a choices param.

If the field is called `gender`, you will have a function on your model called `get_gender_display()` which will return you the string "Male" or "Female".

Comment: I think this is the answer to the question the OP actually wanted, as explained in the comment, as opposed to the question title which makes no sense at all.

Comment: I went for a long shot, tried to extract some understanding of what sort of problem OP may be facing, and provided an answer. If OP accepts this, an edit may be in order to make the question make more sense.